# inserting 2d array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert values of `$array` into MySQL and I'm facing a problem that the values I'm getting in the database are zeros:

```
$v = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $array[0][0]);

mysqli_query($connect, 'INSERT INTO myTable(col)VALUES("'.$V.'")');
```

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables. Even using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not as safe.

Comment: @Barmar especially if you end up using a different variable than the one you escaped ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic He could still get the variables wrong. `$v = $array[0][0]; mysqli_stmt_bind_param("s", $V);`

Comment: @Barmar sure, definitely. I just meant that you could accidentally concat a variable that that you hadn't escaped, which could potentially cause worse problems than just binding the wrong value. Granted, the chances of there just happening to be a `$V` containing some SQL injection seem pretty low, but who knows.

Answer (score 2):

You've set the value to the variable `$v`, but you're using capital `$V` in your SQL when you execute the query. [PHP variables are case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273941/php-case-sensitivity), so `$V` is undefined. It's just a typo, but I'll try to explain how it ends up as a zero in your database.

The undefined variable evaluates to `null`, but you're using it in a string context, so it becomes an empty string. That empty string gets [converted to zero by MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918164/empty-string-inserting-a-zero-not-a-null) when you try to insert it into a numeric type column.

You can catch problems like this if you [enable warnings and notices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) on your development server. PHP will tell you about undefined variables, which will make it easier to avoid problems like this.

Comment: Hey man, real good answer. I was a bit *eesh*  about your saying it was "just a typo" (*lol*), but then continuing to "explain" why it becomes empty etc. Got my vote.

Comment: Thanks @Funk. :) I originally CV'd as typo, but then the comment I was leaving to try to explain why the typo had that effect was getting a little out of hand, so I figured I should just make it an answer.